# No puedo buscar datos en .txt de un registro en C

Tags: c, archivo

Estoy tratando de implementar la función buscar, que pueda buscar en un txt por nombre, es decir dado a un nombre si este es igual al del txt lo imprime y en este caso mi programa no esta haciendo nada. Es decir no me imprime los datos correctamente.

###### Estructura:

```
typedef struct {
    long int cedula;
    char nombre[15];
    int  diab;
    int  mesb;
    int  anob;
}personas;
```

###### Ingreso de datos:

```
char resp;
char fech[10];
char cedu[10];

FILE *f;
personas personas;

printf("\t\tIntroduzca el nombre de la persona\n");
printf (" ->"); fgets(personas.nombre,15,stdin);
verif(personas.nombre);
fflush(stdin);


printf("\t\tIntroduzca la cedula de la persona\n");
printf (" ->"); fgets(cedu,10,stdin);
f=fopen("PersonasInfo.txt","a");
    if (f!=NULL){
        fprintf(f,"%s\n",personas.nombre);
        fprintf(f,"%d\n",personas.cedula);
        fprintf(f,"\n");
    };
fflush(f);
fclose(f);
system("cls");  
printf ("\n\tS E   H A N   G U A R D A D O   T O D O S   S U S   D A T O S!\n\n");
```

###### Función buscar:

```
FILE *f ;
personas personas;
int band = 0;

f = fopen("PersonasInfo.txt","r");
char nom[15];

printf("Nombre a buscar ");
fgets(nom,15,stdin);
verif(nom);

while (!feof(f)){
    fread(&personas,sizeof(personas),1,f);
    
    if (strstr(nom,personas.nombre)!=NULL){
        printf("Nombre %s ",personas.nombre);
        band = 1;
    }
    
    
}

fclose(f);

if (band == 0 ){
    printf("No encotnro");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si escribes en formato texto:

```
fprintf(f,"%s\n",personas.nombre);
fprintf(f,"%d\n",personas.cedula);
fprintf(f,"\n");
```

No puedes leer en formato binario:

```
fread(&personas,sizeof(personas), 1, f);
```

Pongamos un ejemplo, nombre='Pedro', cedula=123.

Lo que guardas en el archivo:

```
P e d r o \n 1 2 3 \n \n
```

Lo que intentas leer:

```
| 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 1A 1B 1C 1D ...
|   cedula   |                   nombre                   | diab
|  P  e  d  r| o \n  1  2  3 \n \n                          <<--- modo texto
| 50 65 64 72|6F 0A 31 32 33 0A 0A XX XX XX XX XX XX XX     <<--- modo binario
```

Como ves, el formato de lectura y el de escritura son incompatibles. Si tu idea es leer en modo binario, guarda en modo binario:

```
fwrite(&personas, sizeof(personas), 1, f);
```

O eso o lees en modo texto, respetando el orden de escritura:

```
fscanf(f, "%s", personas.nombre);
fscanf(f, "%d", &personas.cedula);
fgetc(f); // Para descartar el salto de línea
```

Comment: Okok, no sabia eso muchas gracias, entonces como estoy trabajando con un txt al momento de leer los datos debo hacerlo con un fread respetando el formato de lo que yo quiera que se busque en mi archivo de texto correcto? Por ejemplo en mi funcion buscar deberia hacer exactamente esto

Comment: @AgustinLyon Si escribes en modo texto, lees en modo texto. Si escribes en modo binario, lees en modo binario. La lectura y la escritura deben estar en sincronía, eres tu el que elige el método en cada momento

Comment: Y una pregunta podria usar en este caso tambien el fscanf para leer en modo de texto? Estoy intentando implementar la solucion que me diste con fread pero me da error dev c++ diciendo que son muy pocos argumentos en la funcion y que espera un tamaño.

Comment: @AgustinLyon si, perdona, debes usar `fscanf`, me confundí al pasar el código a la respuesta

Comment: Intente hacerlo asi pero tampoco funciona, digito el nombre pero el .exe no aparece nada, es como si estuviera leyendo pero no devuelve nada :

Comment: Olvidalo ya vi que era! Gracias por el tip del fscanf